# ScrollViewer does not react to the Grid.Row position

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

My StackPanel and ScrollViewer seem to just not end at the Grid.Row position. I am making a Metro app so it is mandatory for the grid to be dynamic, as well as all the elements.

The code:

```
<Grid Background="#FFE4E4E4">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--News/Leaderboard Feed-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">

        </StackPanel>

        <!--Marketplace Feed-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">

        </StackPanel>

        <!--Detailed Marketplace Account-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">

        </StackPanel>


        <!--Marketplace View-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <!--Allows scrolling-->

                <GridView x:Name="MarketplaceFeed" ItemsSource="{Binding StockList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MarketplaceFeedTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <!--Displays the stock markets the user is interested in.-->
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>


            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: You want it to be a 2x2 grid, and you're referring to the Marketplace View, which should be in the top right, correct?  So what's the problem?

Comment: @dbaseman My StackPanel does not adjust to the section it is supposed to be in.  It gets cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the *ScrollViewer* on the outside.  This will auto-fit to the grid, and anything inside it will get the scrolling treatment.

```
   <!--Marketplace View-->
    <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- other content -->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically the stackpanel cannot auto-fit?

Comment: @Rob right, the StackPanel will size according to its contents, it won't snap to its container.